# Magento 2: How to add sidebar for frontend and backend for all pages?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1, magento2.2

how to add sidebar for frontend and backend for all pages in Magento 2?
I can use luma or blank theme.
Example [sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DJB6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the frontend you can create a new page_layout in

> app/design/frontend/Package_name/Theme_name/Magento_Theme/page_layout/

After that you can use that layout in your

> app/design/frontend/Package_name/Theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

No idea about back-end.

Look here for more info: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html#layout-types-page